# Integrating activeCompaign form to nextJs application

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js

I want to add an activeCompaign form in my nextJS application. I have a button that when i click on it it will have to show me the activeCompaign form in a sort of dialog component. but i am not able to do it properly. this is the activeCompaign simple embbeded form tag " "

I am trying to make a dialog component which shows the form and eventually submitting it but when i click on the button to show the dialog i cant see anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.